# How can reverse engineer the list or site definition to caml in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How can reverse engineer the list or site definition to caml in SharePoint 2010? Any tools availble?

Comment: There was a tool called Solution Generator for MOSS 2007, you could point it at a live site or list and it would generate a caml schema for it. It didn't produce the most elegant code/xml but it worked. It came with the Visual Studio 2008 extensions for SharePoint. You also could save the site as a wsp and import it into Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the onet.xml in your 14 hive (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14), which will have the CAML of the site definition you're looking for.